In python, how can/should decorators be used to implement function polymorphism?
Supposing we have a class as follows:
class PersonalChef():
    def cook():
        print("cooking something...")

And we want what it cooks to be a function of the time of day, we could do something like this:
class PersonalChef():
    def cook(time_of_day):
        ## a few ways to do this, but this is quite concise:
        meal = {'morning':'breakfast', 'midday':'lunch', 'evening':'dinner'}[time_of_day]
        print("Cooking", meal)

PersonalChef().cook('morning')
>>> Cooking breakfast

A potentially nice syntax form for this would be using decorators. With some under-the-hood machinery buried inside at_time, it ought to be possible to get it to work like this:
class PersonalChef():
    @at_time('morning')
    def cook():
        print("Cooking breakfast")

    @at_time('midday')
    def cook():
        print("Cooking lunch")

    @at_time('evening')
    def cook():
        print("Cooking dinner")

PersonalChef().cook('morning')
>>> Cooking breakfast

The reason this could be a nice syntax form is shown by how it then shows up in subclasses:
class PersonalChefUK(PersonalChef):
    @at_time('evening')
    def cook():
        print("Cooking supper")

The code written at the sub-class level is extremely minimal and doesn't require any awareness of the base-class implementation/data structures and doesn't require any calls to super() to pass-through the other scenarios. So it could be nice in a situation where there are a large number of people writing derived-classes for whom we want to pack and hide complexity away in the base class and make it hard for them to break the functionality.
However, I've tried a few different ways of implementing this and gotten stuck. I'm quite new to decorators, though, so probably missing something important. Any suggestions/comments?

A simpler approach would be to create a decorator factory that stores the decorated function in a dict that maps the function name and time of day to the function object, and returns a wrapper function that calls the stored function in the first class in the MRO that has it defined for the given time of day:
def at_time(time_of_day, _actions={}):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(self, time_of_day):
            for cls in type(self).__mro__:
                if func := _actions.get((f'{cls.__qualname__}.{name}', time_of_day)):
                    return func(self)
            raise ValueError(f'No {name} found in the {time_of_day} time')
        name = func.__name__
        _actions[func.__qualname__, time_of_day] = func
        return wrapper
    return decorator

so that:
class PersonalChef():
    @at_time('morning')
    def cook(self):
        print("Cooking breakfast")

    @at_time('evening')
    def cook(self):
        print("Cooking dinner")

class PersonalChefUK(PersonalChef):
    @at_time('evening')
    def cook(self):
        print("Cooking supper")

PersonalChef().cook('morning')
PersonalChef().cook('evening')
PersonalChefUK().cook('morning')
PersonalChefUK().cook('evening')

outputs:
Cooking breakfast
Cooking dinner
Cooking breakfast
Cooking supper

Demo: https://ideone.com/9T94sq

You can create a descriptor that acts as a function decorator that when called, stores the decorated function in a mapping of the function's fully qualified name to a dict that maps time of day to the action function, so that when the descriptor's getter function is called, it can return a wrapper function that finds the first class in the MRO that has the action function name defined for the given time of day and calls it:
class at_time:
    actions = {}

    def __init__(self, time_of_day):
        self.time_of_day = time_of_day

    def __call__(self, func):
        self.actions.setdefault(func.__qualname__, {})[self.time_of_day] = func
        return self

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        def wrapper(time_of_day):
            for cls in objtype.__mro__:
                if func := self.actions.get(
                    '.'.join((cls.__qualname__, self.name)), {}).get(time_of_day):
                    return func(obj)
            raise ValueError(f'No {self.name} found in the {time_of_day} time')
        return wrapper

so that:
class PersonalChef():
    @at_time('morning')
    def cook(self):
        print("Cooking breakfast")

    @at_time('evening')
    def cook(self):
        print("Cooking dinner")

class PersonalChefUK(PersonalChef):
    @at_time('evening')
    def cook(self):
        print("Cooking supper")

PersonalChef().cook('morning')
PersonalChef().cook('evening')
PersonalChefUK().cook('morning')
PersonalChefUK().cook('evening')

outputs:
Cooking breakfast
Cooking dinner
Cooking breakfast
Cooking supper

Demo: https://ideone.com/XQEBkK
Alternatively, you can give each overloaded method a private name in the format of _{name}_{time_of_day} so that an attribute lookup with that name will naturally follow MRO:
class at_time:
    actions = {}

    def __init__(self, time_of_day):
        self.time_of_day = time_of_day

    def __call__(self, func):
        self.actions.setdefault(func.__qualname__, {})[self.time_of_day] = func
        return self

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name
        for time_of_day, func in self.actions.pop(
                '.'.join((owner.__qualname__, name))).items():
            setattr(owner, f'_{name}_{time_of_day}', func)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        def wrapper(time_of_day):
            try:
                return getattr(obj, f'_{self.name}_{time_of_day}')()
            except AttributeError:
                raise ValueError(f'No {self.name} found in the {time_of_day} time')
        return wrapper

Demo: https://ideone.com/Mvg2My
